# How to delete/remove a specific table row in mySQL using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I  already have this code:

```
<?php
if ($quantity == 0){
$prd_name = " ";
$colors = " ";
$sizes = " ";
$quantity = " ";
$price = " ";
$TIP = " ";
$TPA = " ";
$cost = " ";
$amount = " ";
$query ="DELETE FROM orders WHERE quantity='0'";
}
?>
```

But it still makes a table row entry.

What I am trying to do is when the inputed number of quantity is 0 then the table row will be deleted. Please bear with me for I'm new in php and mySQL coding.

Comment: just assigning some sql-looking text to a variable doesn't actually DO anything. you still need to execute that query, which means loading up a DB library. Try http://php.net/pdo or http://php.net/mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once run the query by removing **Quotes** to **0** If it's a number

```
<?php
    if($quantity==0)
     {
       $query = "DELETE FROM orders WHERE quantity = 0 ";
       mysql_query($query);
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: thanks. it works now. however, the previous quantity number is still reflected on the table.

Comment: @Ruri: I'm glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to execute the query. It should be

```
$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM orders WHERE quantity='0'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if($quantity==0)
     {
       $query="Delete from orders where quantity=0";
       mysql_query($query);
      }
 ?>
```